# Auto Refresh Web Page with Flask and Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, flask

```
# Python Snippet
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/rand", methods=['GET'])
def random_number():
    return f"{random.randrange(0, 100)}"

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

# -----------------------------------
# HTML Snippet:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"></script>
<script>
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/rand",
      type: "get",
      success: function(response) {
        bar.value = response;
       },
      error: function(xhr) {
          //Handel error
      }
    }); 
}, 1000);
</script>
```

I'm attempting to have the page auto refresh with each random number received, yet I still only see an update after manually refreshing the page.  What am I doing wrong/missing?  Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use regular fetch requests for this instead, no need for ajax. Update your JS to this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
  setInterval(async function() {
    var a = await fetch("/rand")
    var b = await a.text()
    bar.value = b
  }, 1000)
}
```

This does basically what your previous does but is shorter. The problem with your previous script is most likely because you didn't turn get the text from the response object using `.text()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I tried this, but still the same result.  It only updates with a manual reload.  I wonder what else I could be missing...

Comment: Might be because the element hasn't loaded it yet. You might need to add, window.onload, I edited the question. Also can you send what the error in the console shows? Also could you send some HTML snippets of bar?

Comment: Well, you've identified my problem it seems.  Sorry I'm very new to this and was trying to get something basic working.  I don't have any snippets defined for bar.  How would you define it in a situation like mine?

Comment: Just show the code for the bar id you have in your HTML, also did you try adding window.onload?

Comment: This is my problem.  I'm not sure what to put here in my html to create the link...  In my html, I have a line like this:  <h3 id="bar"> **not sure what to put here** </h3>.  How should this be updated to create the link?

Comment: oh use innerHTML instead not value. Value updates values for things like inputs. So instead of bar.value = b use bar.innerHTML = b. That should fix your problem.